# VSCode auto-format code when I use "Remote - SSH" add-on

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I save a file, it no longer auto-formats using prettier. I have it Prettier set as my default and to auto-format on save. It works fine locally, but not when I access files via the add-on and save.

Has anyone else experienced this? Do you have a solution?

Comment: Does the remote device have the prettier addon installed as well?

Comment: Can you add some images to your question?

Comment: Please also detail it, in order to assist you better